# Supplementing box-shadow from parent CSS class

Tags: css

Twitter Bootstrap defines a box-shadow. I'd like to define an inset box shadow, but keep the box-shadow from Bootstrap.

Something like this:

`bootstrap.css`

```
box-shadow: outer shadow
```

Then in my own CSS file

`login.css`

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 0 0 ...
```

Is there a way I can have both apply to an element, without having to redefine the Bootstrap shadow in my login.css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot inherit the box-shadow & change just the inset value, but you could inherit it and then add the custom inset version afterwards.

Here's an example illustrating the inheritance that could be used: http://jsfiddle.net/dwU2P/2/

Example:

```
.parentBox{
    box-shadow:0 0 1em 1em #222;
}
.childBox{
    box-shadow:inherit,
    /* custom inset box-shadow */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you will have to override bootstrap box-shadow.. but you can apply both inset and outset separated with a comma

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 0 0 ..., 0px 3px 0 0 ...;
```